# AngularJS : Routing for some links runs only one time

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngroute

I'm trying to use AngularJS 1.6 for my website and I use ng-route for the routing (because I don't really know ui-router). My problem is that I have many links and one link with parameter :

```
        .when("/", {
            templateUrl : "pages/indexView.html"
        })
        .when("/index", {
            templateUrl : "pages/indexView.html"
        })
        .when("/services", {
            templateUrl : "pages/services.html"
        })
        .when....
        .when("/teams/:team", {
            templateUrl : "pages/teams.html",
            controller : 'TeamsCtrl'
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirect: '/pages/404.html'
        });
```

The controller TeamsCtrl have some conditionals with the parameter `":team"`:

```
        $scope.team = $routeParams.team;

        if($scope.team == 'abc'){
            $scope.Subtitle = 'abc';
            $scope.Description = '';
        } else if ($scope.team == 'fgh'){
            $scope.Subtitle = 'fghfhs';
            $scope.Description = '';                
        } else if ...
```

The problem is that when I first come on the website, I can click on any links from the "teams's links" and it works but if I click on any other link, all the "teams's links" will not run anything (On the other hand the other links still works pretty well).

PS: The links looks like: `href="#!services"` for the normal links and `href="#!teams/abc"` for the "teams's links".

What can I try to fix this?